# Pandas skip header until key found

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am importing a bunch of data files. The format of the files has changed over the years, accumulating more "header" material without any identifying "comment", which makes it hard to know how many lines to skip.

Is there a way in pandas to skip rows until the desired column names are encountered:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
my_names=['A','B','C']
max_head=30
my_file=os.path.join(my_file)
f=open(my_file,'r')
lines=f.readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(lines[:max_head]):
    if line.strip().split()==my_names:
        skiprows=i
a=pd.read_csv(my_file,skiprows=skiprows)
```

And if not, should there be? Something like:

```
pd.read_csv(my_file,start_names=my_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two parts. First find out the row where the matching header is then use that in your `pd.read_csv`

```
def header(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for n,line in enumerate(f):
            if line.startswith("whatever_the_header_name_is"):
                return n
```

You can now pass the above function into read_csv like this
`pd.read_csv (file_name, header=header(file_name))`